# Are all of these tweeted examples of spaceflight failures US failures?

Tags: history, failure, united-states, mission-anomaly

This [verified tweet](https://twitter.com/azarijahromi/status/1226556188109819905) from [MJ Azari Jahromi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammad-Javad_Azari_Jahromi), ICT Minister of Iran, found in Livescience's [Iran satellite launch fails to reach orbit](https://www.livescience.com/iran-satellite-launch-failure-zafar-1.html) says:

> Today "Zafar" satellite launch failed. Like many scientific projects, Failure happened. FALCON 9, Juno II, ATLAS, PROTON M, ANTARES are just few samples of US launch failures.
>
> But We're UNSTOPPABLE! We have more Upcoming Great Iranian Satellites!

Are all of these really examples of US launch failures?

Comment: One of these things is not like the others...

Comment: Wow. Juno II. Going back in time for that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proton is Russian, and of course has failed, and badly recently.

They skipped Ariane which had some early launch failures. India and Japan had lost vehicles as well. Everyone has launch failures at some point. (A more interesting question might be, is there a booster without a launch failure, defined as loss of mission/payload?  Saturn V, Falcon Heavy come to mind as examples).

Falcon 9 had a full loss of mission in flight, CRS-7 and then during a hot fire test, with the payload attached, AMOS-7 blew up on the pad.

He could have listed Titan's many failures.  Famous on in 1986 just after the Shuttle. Did not list either loss of Shuttles. (Challenger would have counted, Columbia less so in context).

He makes a fair point that lots of boosters fail.

Specific to answer the question, Falcon 9, Juno, Atlas, and Antares are all US boosters. Proton M and Proton (all variants) are Russian boosters.

Comment: Plenty of Deltas also. I find it amusing that he picked on Juno II.